# Swift delegate function not called from NSObject class (not a 2 ViewController scenario)

Tags: swift, delegates

Sorry, yes it's yet another question asking for help with Swift protocols. Have used these just fine in the past between two VC's using the prepare(ForSegue...) standard. BUT, my situation does not include 2 VC's.

In my app, I have a view controller (call it VC A) that has a slide out settings menu that includes an option to change a group image. The functionality of the settings menu is working fine except the imageView displayed on VC A is not getting updated (unless the user leaves the VC and comes back). The delegate function on VC A is not executing when the settings menu option completes.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have a Protocols.swift file for the various delegate protocols I'm using. The protocol for this situation:

```
protocol UpdateGroupImageviewDelegate: class {

    func updateGroupImageview()

}
```

The slide out setttings menu relevant code:

```
class GroupSettingsLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

weak var delegate: UpdateGroupImageviewDelegate?

    // rest of the settings menu code, including one that executes the imagePicker

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // do the normal imagePicker stuff to get the selected image
    // store the image, etc.

    // call delegate method to update group image on chat screen
    print("ABOUT TO CALL DELEGATE FOR UPATEGROUPIMAGEVIEW")  // this prints correctly

    self.delegate?.updateGroupImageview()

     }

}
```

Code from viewController A:

```
class GroupChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UpdateGroupImageviewDelegate {

// Delegate Variable
var updateGroupImageviewDelegate: GroupSettingsLauncher?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set this VC as the delegate for updating the group Imageview
        updateGroupImageviewDelegate?.delegate = self

       // rest of code

}

func updateGroupImageview() {
        print("*** updateGroupImageview has been called!") // This is not printing

    }

}
```

Comment: Your implementation looks correct. First thing to check would be is your delegate reference still there before you call updateGroupImageview. Add print(delegate) in the imagePickerController(_:didFinish...:) function and check that delegate isn’t nil.

Comment: I believe you are not initializing 'updateGroupImageviewDelegate' but just declaring it.

Comment: `updateGroupImageviewDelegate ` withing viewDidLoad. is it initialized or you are just setting delegate for a nil object.

Comment: iOSer & RJE - thanks. That was exactly my problem. Hadn't initialized the updateGroupImageviewDelegate, just declared it. THANKS! Works like a charm now. I'm not seeing the check mark to indicate a correct answer, but have upvoted you both.